# Fullscreen mode in Firefox exits when navigating pages inside an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, iframe

I hope someone can help me. Here's a rundown on my situation:

**Feature intended:** I want to run pages inside an iFrame while the parent is in full screen, so that full screen mode is preserved.

**What I've done so far:**

Fullscreen script-- I scraped the following code from SO to call a fullscreen mode

```
   var docElm = document.documentElement;
            if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
                docElm.requestFullscreen();
            }
            else if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();
            }
            else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen();
            }
            else if (docElm.msRequestFullscreen) {
                docElm.msRequestFullscreen();
            }
```

Iframe structure: Now in my index page, I have the following:

```
<iframe src="http://domain/somepage.php" name="myiframe" allowFullScreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

**Where it's working:** the fullscreen function fires successfully, and I am able to keep the parent page at fullscreen while I navigate to different pages loaded inside the iFrame.

So I'd say that the feature I wanted is working fine-- that is, when using Chrome (v.52)

**PROBLEM:** It doesn't work in Firefox.  Specifically: the fullscreen function successfully fires, but when I navigate the pages inside the iFrame, the fullscreen mode exits.

Can anybody give me advise as to why this is working in Chrome but not in Firefox? Thanks,

Comment: Do you get same behavior when you enable full screen via browser options (F11 for Windows, I think) as opposed to requesting full screen via script?

Comment: F11 for both browsers work fine.  I have actually implemented a notification for Firefox users to use F11 instead. However, I (1) wanted to know why Chrome is able to mimic F11's (persistent) fullscreen through a programmatic call (request) while Firefox can't; and (2) if there's something I can do through the code to make Firefox handle it like Chrome does.

Comment: Best guess is that since browser must ask for permission for full screen, maybe FF doesn't respect the granted permission when iframe `src` changes. Sounds like possible FireFox bug.. not sure whether that open source project is being actively maintained any more because recent figures I've seen show FireFox usage rates are very low and dropping rapidly, but you might want to submit bug to their bug tracker system anyway, if it is still up.

Comment: Thought as much. I'll work towards locking in usage to chrome and safari, since it's for a corporate application after all. Thank you!